Register all annotated classes to be available in native run
What I need to do to have all classes annotated with custom annotation being visible in native run?
I know it needs to be registrered during processAot (compile phase) before native application starts.
What is the correct way of doing it? BeanRegistrationAotProcessor or ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar?
Is there any simple way of registering all classes having annotation so the list is available in native run?
I figured out I can use BeanRegistrationAotProcessor or ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar to add this classes to BeanDefinitions and it works but maybe there is simpler way of doing that.
First approach:
EnableKafkaMessages to import registrar:
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Import(KafkaMessages.KafkaMessagesRegistrar::class)
annotation class EnableKafkaMessages

Here I pass found classes to constructor or set the member value:
class KafkaMessageSupport(val classes: Set<Class<*>>) {

    class KafkaMessagesRegistrar : ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
        override fun registerBeanDefinitions(metadata: AnnotationMetadata, registry: BeanDefinitionRegistry) {
            val kafkaMessages = findKafkaMessages(metadata)

            if (registry.containsBeanDefinition(BEAN)) {
                val beanDefinition = registry.getBeanDefinition(BEAN)
                beanDefinition.constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, kafkaMessages)
            } else {
                val mongockSupportBeanDefinitionBuilder =
                    BeanDefinitionBuilder
                        .rootBeanDefinition(KafkaMessageSupport::class.java)
                        .addConstructorArgValue(kafkaMessages)

                registry.registerBeanDefinition(BEAN, mongockSupportBeanDefinitionBuilder.beanDefinition)
            }
        }

        private fun findKafkaMessages(metadata: AnnotationMetadata): MutableSet<Class<*>> {
            // not relevant
            ... return classes containg KafkaMessage annotation
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val BEAN: String = KafkaMessageSupport::class.java.name
    }
}

Real case of using it:
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaMessages
class KafkaTopicResolverConfiguration(private val kafkaMessageSupport: KafkaMessageSupport) {
    @Bean
    fun kafkaTopics(applicationContext: ApplicationContext): KafkaTopicResolver {
        return KafkaTopicResolver(kafkaMessageSupport.classes.associateWith { it.simpleName } )}
}

And here I satisfy intelliJ so it does not shout about missing bean:

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableKafkaMessages
class KafkaMessagesConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    fun kafkaMessages() = KafkaMessages(setOf())
}


Second approach:
@Configuration
class MongockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun mongockRunnerSupport() = MongockRunnerSupport()
}

And AotProcessor:
class ChangeUnitBeanRegistrationAotProcessor : BeanRegistrationAotProcessor {
    override fun processAheadOfTime(registeredBean: RegisteredBean): BeanRegistrationAotContribution? {
        if (registeredBean.beanClass == MongockRunnerSupport::class.java) {
            return object : RegisteredBeanAotContribution {
                override fun applyTo(
                    generationContext: GenerationContext,
                    beanRegistrationCode: BeanRegistrationCode
                ) {
                    source.mergedBeanDefinition.propertyValues.addPropertyValue(
                        "changeUnitClasses",
                        AnnotatedTypeScanner(ChangeUnit::class.java).findTypes(
                            "io.mongock.runner.core.executor.system.changes",
                            "me.tmarciniak.springbootstarter"
                        )
                    )
                }

                override fun getSource(): RegisteredBean {
                    return registeredBean
                }
            }
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}

Conclusion
The main difference is that ImportRegistrar is invoked only for KafkaMessages bean in opposition to AotProcessor which is invoked for every bean and I need to check if the bean is instance of expected type. Additionally in AotProcessor I can set parameter value to existing bean defined in @Configuration class instead creating new bean and passing values through contructor. The Import registrar drawback is that I need to define bean with @CondionalOnMissingBean annotation just to satisfy Intellij.
Results

  public static BeanDefinition getMongockRunnerSupportBeanDefinition() {
    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(MongockRunnerSupport.class);
    beanDefinition.getPropertyValues().addPropertyValue("changeUnitClasses", Set.of(AddEntityViewCollection00001.class, SystemChangeUnit00001.class));
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(getMongockRunnerSupportInstanceSupplier());
    return beanDefinition;
  }


And with Aot processor:

 public static BeanDefinition getKafkaMessagesBeanDefinition() {
    RootBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new RootBeanDefinition(KafkaMessages.class);
    beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().addIndexedArgumentValue(0, Set.of(EntityUpdatedEventMessage.class, EntityCreatedEventMessage.class, EntityDeletedEventMessage.class));
    beanDefinition.setInstanceSupplier(getKafkaMessagesInstanceSupplier());
    return beanDefinition;
  }


Answer to my own question
I prefer to use ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar. It is not so powerful as aot processor which can process all beans but is dedicated to imported single bean. I don't need to define @Bean in @Configuration class, I can simply add it to @Import:
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Import(ChangeUnitSupport::class, ChangeUnitSupport.ChangeUnitsRegistrar::class)
annotation class EnableChangeUnits

I can also check if bean exists and react:
class ChangeUnitSupport(val changeUnitClasses: Set<Class<*>>) {

    class ChangeUnitsRegistrar : ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {
        override fun registerBeanDefinitions(metadata: AnnotationMetadata, registry: BeanDefinitionRegistry) {
            val annotation: Class<out Annotation> = EnableChangeUnits::class.java
            val attributes = metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(annotation.name)
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("Unable to obtain annotation attributes for $annotation")
            val annotationAttributes = AnnotationAttributes(attributes)
            val packages = annotationAttributes.getStringArray("basePackages").toList()
            val findChangeUnits = findChangeUnits(packages)

            if (registry.containsBeanDefinition(BEAN)) {
                val beanDefinition = registry.getBeanDefinition(BEAN)
                beanDefinition.constructorArgumentValues.addIndexedArgumentValue(0, findChangeUnits)
            } else {
                val mongockSupportBeanDefinitionBuilder =
                    BeanDefinitionBuilder
                        .rootBeanDefinition(ChangeUnitSupport::class.java)
                        .addConstructorArgValue(findChangeUnits)

                registry.registerBeanDefinition(BEAN, mongockSupportBeanDefinitionBuilder.beanDefinition)
            }
        }

        private fun findChangeUnits(packages: List<String>): MutableSet<Class<*>> =
            AnnotatedTypeScanner(ChangeUnit::class.java).findTypes(packages)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val BEAN: String = ChangeUnitSupport::class.java.name
    }
}

Additionally ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar is not related to AOT itself so it will work for regular spring application and native one.
I went through Spring AOT contribution classes and it supports generics, but annotated classes have to be handled manually.
Maybe in future Spring could have possibility to define something like this:
@EnableAnnotatedClassesSupport(annotationName = "xyz", packages=["com.xyz"], supportClass=sample.Xyz)

I imagine it can create Xyz bean with injected classes to its classes member.

Please add a [mre] with real code instead of talking about your code.

Thanks, good point! Hope it is clear now.

Your question contains an answer. If you have an answer, then post it as a separate answer, not as part of your question. (Self-answering a question is okay)
